# Need help with weighted grades calculation

Tags: percentages

I can't quite see how to solve this, so help will be appreciated.

I want to see if I can ever recover from this situation and what my final projected grade could be based on this. I list my grade in each category and the weight it carries toward the final grade.

```
Grade     Weight
```

Lectures
51.06%     ;   5%

Recitation
43.75%     ;  10%

Tests
30.42%     ;  30%

Online
42.10%     ;  25%

Labs
 _____     ;  10%

Final Exam
 _____     ;  20%

My Total Average Grade at the moment is 42.11%

About what percentage in my remaining work would I need to reach 70%, if that's even possible?
Note that I don't have exact numbers but we are approximately HAlfway through the semester, with a pretty even amount of work on each half.
As for the Tests, I have completed 2/3 tests, so just 1 test with a weight of 30% left, if that information is relevant at all.

Thanks and please show me how you did it.

Comment: Assuming you get 100 on the remaining, this will bring you to 72.11

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how u found that?

Comment: Would the amount of remaining material in the course matter?

Comment: The relative contribution of each missing grade is based on its percentage multiplied by the grade.

Comment: Amount of material is not relevant. You had to work harder before...:)